# Spring Boot Multi Module application with @SpringBootConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I have a maven multi module app with the structure :

```
-parent_project
-actual_project
-jpaBase
```

Parent project is a maven aggregation of the projects : actual_project and jpaBase (both spring boot applications)

jpaBase is a dependency of actual_project.

Now when i do a mvn package I am getting a unit test error :

Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes

because both jpaBase and actual_project have classes annotated with @SpringBootConfiguration.

How can I make sure that Spring considers the SpringBootConfiguration class of only actual_project and not of jpaBase.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `jpaBase` an actual application which needs to run independently or just the persistence layer for your `actual_project`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Spring documentation :

> Application should only ever include one @SpringBootConfiguration and
>   most idiomatic Spring Boot applications will inherit it from
>   @SpringBootApplication.

You said :

> because both jpaBase and actual_project have classes annotated with
>   @SpringBootConfiguration.

It should not. This annotation has to be used a single time by application. So, only actual_project and parent_project which are Spring Boot applications should declare this annotation.

`@SpringBootConfiguration` replaces the declaration of these annotations:
`@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`

You have the information [in the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation).

So, in your jpaBase project, you could replace 
`@SpringBootConfiguration` by the declaration of these three annotations :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({ "yourPackage" })
public class JpaConfig {
   ....
}
```

Comment: The build was failing after replacing the SpringBootApplication annotation for the jpaBase project, as now it wasn't able to find any SpringBootApplication clsas for jpaBase.
But based on your suggestion I have now removed jpaBase as a SpringBootApplication by moving the SpringBootDependencies from the parent project section to dependency management section in the parent_project pom. It works now

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for anyone looking at this, `SpringBootConfiguration` only replaces `@Configuration`.

`@SpringBootApplication` replaces `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.